# JS did'nt work in "return array('html' => $response);"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, return, response

I have a PHP file that outputs products based on a WP_Query.

Everything works so far!

But now **I want to output javascript** in the return as well. And this is not recognized / loaded ... For me, it looks like javascript is not recognized as a javascript. If I insert an alert this will be ignored.

```
...
if ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) : $posts_gf->the_post();
        $response .= '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        </script>
        <div class="item col-md-4">
            Produkt
        </div>
        ';
    endwhile;
...
```

I want to load a carousel from a js which is include in functions.php.
If I paste the same code for the carousel directly into the template-part file "content-glasfaser.php" it works.

[image: the output]

Here is the excerpt from the file where the carousel should load (all js/css files are loading/existing in header and footer):

```
    $products = self::$productDefinitions[$result['Standorttyp']];

    $posts_gf = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'tarife',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__in' => $products,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tarif_kategorie',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'glasfaser',
            ),
        ),
    ));



    $street = utf8_encode($result['Strasse']);
    $houseNo = $result['Hausnummer'];
    $postCode = $result['Plz'];
    $city = $result['Ort'];


    $response = '
    <h3>inside return</h3>
    <section class="regular slider">';

    // Zeige die Glasfaser-Tarife

    if ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) : $posts_gf->the_post();
            $response .= '
                <div class="item col-md-4">
                    Produkt
                </div>
            ';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        $response .= '';

    endif;  


    return array('html' => $response);

    }
}
```

EDIT:
For the carousel i've insert 3 files in my functions.php (wordpress)

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'xxx-slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css', array(), '20170925' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'xxx-slidertheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick-theme.css', array(), '20170925' );  
... 
wp_enqueue_script( 'xxx-sliderjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js', array(), '20190218', true );
```

- All these files are loading in header/footer.
- The carousel should run inside an already loaded php.
- The script is from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and it's worked in the "already loaded" file. But not inside the ajax(?).

Comment: Did you look at the source code in the browser? Does the JS part appear there? However, what kind of JS exactly do you want to output? Because maybe a different approach would be better in this case.

Comment: @ChrisG yes. The JS code appears (for example the alert) and in footer and header all files are included.

Comment: @ChrisG In the first step, it would be enough for me when the alert is issued. Then this could may be the solution why the code from the "external" js file is not recognized.

Comment: How is the carousel code inserted into the main document? Are you loading it via AJAX? Because in that case, the JS code won't run on its own. `In the first step, it would be enough for me when the alert is issued.` I understand that this is your approach, but I still think a different approach is more suitable here. As in: the carousel code isn't part of the AJAX HTML but already loaded in a `<script>`, and after inserting the carousel, the init code is called.

Comment: @ChrisG i've edit my question. It's too confusing in comment :-D

Comment: So what JS exactly do you want to output in your Tarife loop? Sorry, I'm convinced by now that this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/); please ask about your problem, not about your attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all your code it seems like you're injecting the reply from php into an already loaded html page right?

If that is the case the JS won't be executed unless you explicitly call it.
I Would sovle this by reformating your JS so you're left with a single script and call a function within that script after loading your html.

```
$response = '
<script> function initialize { alert("Hello! I am an alert box!"); } </script>
<h3>inside return</h3>
<section class="regular slider">';

// Zeige die Glasfaser-Tarife

if ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) :
```

then you can call this after loading with:

```
//Code that loads your php result
initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

[How do I execute a javascript after Ajax load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552250/how-do-i-execute-a-javascript-after-ajax-load)

I've insert this to my js

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
  // carouselcode
});
```